# What VLC keyboard shortcut is triggered by control-shift-pageup on Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player

I'm using [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) 3.0.1 on a MacBook. I'm also using [Moom](https://manytricks.com/moom/) (a move/zoom windows app).

My Moom shortcut to throw the window to my upper display is <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>up</kbd>—which, being a MacBook, translates to <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>page up</kbd>, since the MacBook has no 10-key pad.

In VLC, my shortcut is instead increasing the size of the window by roughly 20%, and it sometimes also is moving the window leftward (sometimes even offscreen).

Strangely, my Moom shortcut to throw the window to my lower display (<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>down</kbd>/<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>page down</kbd>) isn't interrupted by VLC.

I've looked through all keyboard shortcuts in the menubar, and I've looked through all shortcuts in VLC Prefs -> Hotkeys. I see no shortcuts under VLC prefs -> Show All.

I'd like to remove or overwrite the unwanted VLC shortcut, but what is it?

Comment: I'm not seeing any ctrl/shift commands at all in VLC; nor does your command produce any effect for me. I'd try resetting VLC's prefs & if no change, look elsewhere - maybe system prefs>keyboard>shortcuts

Comment: I've just discovered that if I change the Moom shortcut to a different combination, the move action still fails. Thus it'd seem not to be a key-combination clash. I've created a ticket with Moom, and I'll update this SU question when I've more info. Thanks.